# Spring Boot/ Spring Security, login form, username is irrelevant

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have written an APP which has the login form implemented so far.

I use Spring-Boot 2.x, Java 9 and Security ofc.

My tests showed that it actually doesn't matter what username the user enters in the login form, every username will be accepted as long the password of the user is correct.

This confuses me really much.

I hope someone here can help. If you have any other suggestions for improving my code your oppinion please let me know.

**SecurityConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        // Setting Service to find User in the database.
        // And Setting PassswordEncoder
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // disable Cross Site Request Forgery
        http.csrf().disable();

        // The pages does not require login
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/login", "/register")
                .permitAll();

        // userInfo page requires login as ROLE_USER or ROLE_ADMIN.
        // If no login, it will redirect to /login page.
        // TODO ask if I really have to add every route here manually
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/selectGet", "/success")
                .access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')");

        // When the user is not admin
        // But access a page that requires admin role,
        // AccessDeniedException will be thrown.
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403");

        // Config for Login Form
        http.authorizeRequests().and().formLogin()//
                // Submit URL of login page.
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check") // Submit URL
                .loginPage("/login")//
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/success")//
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")//
                .usernameParameter("username")//
                .passwordParameter("password")
                // Config for Logout Page
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/logoutSuccessful");
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (userRepo.count() < 1) {
            System.out.println("SpringUser not found! " + userName);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("SpringUser " + userName + " was not found in the database");
        }
        return userRepo.findAll().iterator().next();
    }
}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class SpringUser implements UserDetails {

    // TODO https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    /*  @NotNull
      @Size(min = 2, max = 30)*/
    private String username;

    /*    @NotNull
        @Size(min = 4, max = 30)*/
    private String password;

    public SpringUser() {
    }

    public SpringUser(final String username, final String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = EncrytedPasswordUtils.encrytePassword(password);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantList = new ArrayList<>();
        grantList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        return grantList;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Relevant methods from the controller**

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String registerPost(@RequestParam("username") String username,
                           @RequestParam("password") String password) {
    System.out.println("post Register");
    SpringUser springUser = new SpringUser(username, password);
    userRepo.save(springUser);
    return "redirect:";
}
```

**Register html**

```
  <form method="post" th:action="@{/register}" >
                <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="username" placeholder="username" maxlength="10">
                <input type="text" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="password" placeholder="password">
                <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Register">
            </form>
```

**Login html**

Comment: Where/how are you storing the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        if (userRepo.count() < 1) {
            System.out.println("SpringUser not found! " + userName);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("SpringUser " + userName + " was not found in the database");
        }
        return userRepo.findAll().iterator().next();
    }
}
```

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html)

> **Locates the user based on the username.** In the actual implementation, the search may possibly be case sensitive, or case insensitive depending on how the implementation instance is configured. In this case, the UserDetails object that comes back may have a username that is of a different case than what was actually requested.

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

So, you are supposed to be locating the `UserDetails` **by userName**. Your code ignores the `userName` and does:

```
userRepo.findAll().iterator().next();
```

i.e. you just grab all the users, then you take the first one and return it.

Your code should do:

```
userRepo.findByUsername(userName);
```

You need to determine whether there is a `UserDetails` in the `UserRepo` with a `userName` that matches the username submitted on the form.

---

TL;DR: The username is ignored because you ignore the username.